# Converting Text file in csv using python

Tags: python, pandas, string

[image]

How to convert the following text file into csv files having same columns as User, Name, Company, Session, Description, Start and End

### Data:05-20-21[15:55, Eur]   User History by user                 page:1

### User| Name           | Comapny | Session| Description | Start      |    End
|                |         |        |             | Date | Time| Date|Time|

Acanter|ANdy Canter| 135      |Ott   | ttstpdeman | 05-19-21|07:48|05-19-21|08:13
|           | 135      | ttspt|Thin client| 05-19-21|07:48|05-19-21 |08:13

Date: 06-20-21[15:55, Eur]  User History by user                   page: 2

Comment: It containes - + [ ]

Comment: It would help a lot if you copy your text in the question.

Comment: First you'll have to ensure all the rows contain same number of `|`. 
So read the file in python and remove the rows which are irrelevant like the ones containing `---+--` or the lines on the top containing headings and page number.

Then you can use `read_csv(filename, sep='|')` and see if it works for you. You can use `.strip()` after reading the file to remove the blank spaces. Since you've provided an image of the text file, I can't help you further

Comment: What have you tried so far ? SO sommunity is not here to do your own tasks ...

Comment: @Steven I have tried many things I will post it tomorrow. Hope you will help me

Comment: @Shubham. Thanks for the help I will try to post file or some lines for your reference. I will also post what I have done so far.

Comment: import pandas as pd file1 = open("userhistory.txt","r+") with open("userhistory_aam50100.txt") as text_file: file1 = text_file.read() print(file1) bad_chars = [';', '+', '!', "*",'-']  for i in bad_chars :
    file1 = file1.replace(i, '')  with open ("file2.txt" , "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(file1)   df5 =pd.read_csv("file2.txt", index = None)    df5.to_csv('df6.csv', index = None)     dataframe6 = pd.read_csv("df6.csv")   dataframe6.to_csv('df7.csv', index = None)    dataframe7 = pd.read_csv("df7.csv", delimiter = '|')   dataframe7.to_csv("df8.csv")

Comment: @Shubham    1. I removed first 2 lines manually in excel. 2. then I removed all --- and +++ characters. I saved this text file. I reopened this text file in pandas using delimiter as '|' . I am getting a required dataframe. But here the problem is when I tried to remove ----,  It removed - (seperator) in date column also.

Comment: yeah it doesn't matter if it removes the `'` in date column because you can always convert it to a date by specifying the format `mmddyy` instead of `mm-dd-yy`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you read the file line by line using a for loop. I would try to parse and convert it in three steps:

**Step 1**: header (from start to the first line consisting of only "-")

This one is quite special. You can use a counter to indicate the current line and extract the relevant information using `split()` and `strip()`.

**Step 2**: column names (from the first line consisting of only "-" to the first line consisting of only "-" and "+")

Try reading each line and if it does not contain a "-" then use `split("|")` to split into the cells and `strip()` to get rid of the spaces. After that you only have to combine the cells with the separator of your choice and write them to your file.

The only issue here are the combined cells (start and end) which you could handle similar to Step 1 if you always have the same column names or you can try to go by the start-locations of each cell by reading the part twice: one time for reading the start-locations of each cell (all occurrences of "|") and one time for the data and conversion.
In that case you can iterate over the start-locations for each line and test if each line has a "|" at those locations and if not you ignore the cell if not you can create a sub-string starting at your start-location and split to get the data in the cell (`line[start:].split("|", 1)[0]`)

**Step 3**: data (from the first line consisting of only "-" and "+" to the end)

Read each line and collapse each occurrence of multiple spaces into one while replacing each "|" with your separator:

```
import re

line = re.sub(" *\| *", "[separator]", line)
```

After that you can just write the line to your output file.

Comment: import pandas as pd                                                                                                             file1 = open("userhistory.txt","r+")                                                                                  with open("userhistory_aam50100.txt") as text_file:
file1 = text_file.read()
print(file1)                                                                                                               
bad_chars = [';', '+', '!', "*",'-']